# Get city id from ajax generating city select box to my original php page

Tags: php, ajax

In my registration form there are many form elements to give users' details for registration in my web site. among those elements there are two select boxes for user to select their district and city. I have created these two select box using ajax. Therefore a user select a district then automatically ajax creating second select box for cities is populating. I used separate PHP page called findcity.php to create city select box. I called this findcity.php page from my original register.php page through onChange attribute. and there I passed the district id with the url to findcity.php page. like wise,

Now I need to bring city id to my original register.php page when user select a city from city select box in findcity.php page. my problem is that. I tried to get city Id to register.php page but still I couldn't get it. city id is needed me to send to the database with other form elements' values.

can anybody help me to fix my problem?

here is my coding for your reference.

This code is, from my register.php page

```
<div>
<label for="district">District <img src="../images/required_star.png" alt="required" /> : </label>
<?php

require_once ('../includes/config.inc.php');    
require_once( MYSQL2 );

$query="select * from district order by district_id";
$result = mysqli_query( $dbc, $query);

    echo '<select name="district" class="text" onChange="getCity(' . "'" . 'findcity.php?district=' . "'" . '+this.value)">';
    echo '<option value="">-- Select District --</option>';

    while( $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_NUM)) { 
        echo '<option value="' . $row[0] . '"';

        // Check for stickyness: 
        if ( isset( $_POST['district']) && ( $_POST['district'] == $row[0] ))    
            echo ' selected="selected"';

            echo " >$row[1]</option>";    
    }
    echo '</select>';
?> 

</div>    
<div>
<label for="city">City <img src="../images/required_star.png" alt="required" /> : </label>
<input type="hidden" name="reg_locationid" id="reg_locationid" value="56" />
<div id="citydiv" style="position: relative; top: -14px; left: 130px; margin-bottom: -26px;">
    <select name="city" class="text">
        <option>-- Select City --</option>
    </select>
</div>
</div>
```

this is, from my findcity.php page

```
<?php

$districtId=$_GET['district'];

require_once ('../includes/configaration.inc.php'); 
require_once( MYSQLCONNECTION );

$query="select city_id, city_name from city2 where district_id=$districtId";
$result=mysqli_query( $dbc, $query);



echo '<select name="city" class="text">
    <option>-- Select City --</option>';

while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_NUM)) { 

echo '<option value="' . $row[0] . '"';

// Check for stickyness: 
if ( isset( $_POST['city']) && ( $_POST['city'] == $row[0] )) { 
    echo ' selected="selected"';

    //echo '<input type="hidden" name="city"  value="' . $row[0] . '"'; 

}
    echo " >$row[1]</option>";  

}

echo '</select>';

?>
```

These are ajax functions

```
function getXMLHTTP() { //function to return the xml http object
var xmlhttp=false;  
try{
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
catch(e)    {       
    try{            
        xmlhttp= new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    catch(e){
        try{
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
        }
        catch(e1){
            xmlhttp=false;
        }
    }
}

return xmlhttp;
}



function getCity(strURL) {      

    var req = getXMLHTTP();

    if (req) {

        req.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (req.readyState == 4) {
                // only if "OK"
                if (req.status == 200) {                        
                document.getElementById('citydiv').innerHTML=req.responseText;                      
            } else {
                alert("There was a problem while using XMLHTTP:\n" + req.statusText);
            }
        }               
    }           
    req.open("GET", strURL, true);
    req.send(null);
}

}
```

any comments are greatly appreciated.

Comment: And what error was it giving you?

Comment: there is no any error. Just I need to get cityId to my register.php page..

Comment: Is the city dropdown list populating when you select a district?

Comment: yes... when user select a district then my city dropdown list populating according to that selected district. Its working for me.. my problem is when Im try to get user selected city name or its id.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the city is not selected in your findcity.php page check that!

also try clearing up citydiv's innerhtml before you replace it.